# Replace comma only when between quotation marks

Tags: python, str-replace

I have to replace strings like this one:

```
-- 1234,BUCARAMANGA,"KM 15 VIA QUE CONDUCE AGUACHICA-BUCARAMANGA, CORREGIMIENTO EL JUNCAL"
```

and turn them into strings like this one (removing the comma in between the quotation amrks)

```
-- 1234,BUCARAMANGA,"KM 15 VIA QUE CONDUCE AGUACHICA-BUCARAMANGA CORREGIMIENTO EL JUNCAL"
```

I'm using this code:

```
f1 = open('FACMES.txt', 'r',encoding ='utf-8')
f2 = open('FACMES_2.txt', 'w',encoding ='utf-8')

checkWords = ("KM 15 VIA QUE CONDUCE AGUACHICA-BUCARAMANGA, CORREGIMIENTO EL JUNCAL","COOPERATIVA TECNICOS, TECNOLOGOS PROFESIONALES COOTETECPRO","3 KMS DE LA VÍA FLORENCIA - PAUJIL, DE LA Y A MANO DERECHA DELANTE PTO ARANGO")
repWords = ("KM 15 VIA QUE CONDUCE AGUACHICA-BUCARAMANGA CORREGIMIENTO EL JUNCAL","COOPERATIVA TECNICOS TECNOLOGOS PROFESIONALES COOTETECPRO","3 KMS DE LA VÍA FLORENCIA - PAUJIL DE LA Y A MANO DERECHA DELANTE PTO ARANGO")

for line in f1:
    for check, rep in zip(checkWords, repWords):
        line = line.replace(check, rep)
    f2.write(line)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Is there some way to replace the comma only when the comma is between double quotes and other characters?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @khelwood You're right, I should've pay more attention.

Comment: Does [Remove All Commas Between Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336518/remove-all-commas-between-quotes) answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to look for a quotation mark, followed by one or more characters (`(.+)` in the pattern), followed by a comma, followed by one or more characters, followed by another quotation mark.

These groups of one or more characters form capture groups, which we then refer to using `\1` and `\2` in the call to `re.sub()`.

Using only `.replace()` is going to be a bit complicated here:

```py
import re
data = '-- 1234,BUCARAMANGA,"KM 15 VIA QUE CONDUCE AGUACHICA-BUCARAMANGA, CORREGIMIENTO EL JUNCAL"'

pattern = r'"(.+),(.+)"'
result = re.sub(pattern, r'"\1\2"', data)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
-- 1234,BUCARAMANGA,"KM 15 VIA QUE CONDUCE AGUACHICA-BUCARAMANGA CORREGIMIENTO EL JUNCAL"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stringData =  '"KM 15 VIA QUE CONDUCE AGUACHICA-BUCARAMANGA, CORREGIMIENTO EL JUNCAL","COOPERATIVA TECNICOS, TECNOLOGOS PROFESIONALES COOTETECPRO","3 KMS DE LA VÍA FLORENCIA - PAUJIL, DE LA Y A MANO DERECHA DELANTE PTO ARANGO"'

list_of_elements = stringData.split('","')
cleaned_list_of_elements = []
for element in list_of_elements:
    if(list_of_elements.index(element) == 0):
        cleaned_list_of_elements.append(element[1:].replace(',', ''))
    elif(list_of_elements.index(element) == len(list_of_elements) - 1):
        cleaned_list_of_elements.append(element[:len(element) - 1].replace(',', ''))
    else:
        cleaned_list_of_elements.append(element.replace(',', ''))
print(cleaned_list_of_elements)
```